# Google Script, how can I include words with an apostrophe in my word limit for my regex search?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Pretty inexperienced coder here, I have recently gotten a script working that uses regex to search for two different words occurring within a certain word limit. So I can search for "the" and "account" occurring within 10 words of each other, then my script prints the sentence it occurs in. However, I have recently found out that if any words between "the" and "account" contain an apostrophe, my code doesn't work to find this occurrence. So for example, if I want to find a sentence that contains "the" and "account" such as: "I am here to check why the money isn't in my account" then my script would not work because an apostrophe word, "isn't", is between my search terms "the" and "account". If this isn't clear enough please don't hesitate to comment and ask. 
Here is my script:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var historySheet = ss.getSheetByName('master');  
var resultsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('results');
var totalRowsWithData = historySheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
var data = historySheet.getRange(1, 1, totalRowsWithData, 3).getValues(); 
var regexp = /\W*(the)\W*\s+(\w+\s+){0,10}(account)|(account)\s+(\w+\s+){0,10}(the)/i;
var result = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
     var row = data[i];
     var column = row[0];
     if (regexp.exec(column) !== null) {
        result.push(row); }}
if (result.length > 0) {
    var resultsSheetDataRows = resultsSheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
    resultsSheetDataRows = resultsSheetDataRows === 1 ? resultsSheetDataRows : resultsSheetDataRows + 1; 
    var resultsSheetRange = resultsSheet.getRange(resultsSheetDataRows, 1, result.length, 3);
  resultsSheetRange.setValues(result);}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `(\w+\s+)` to `([\w']+\s+)`

That is, the whole regex should look like this:

```
/\W*(the)\W*\s+([\w']+\s+){0,10}(account)|(account)\s+([\w']+\s+){0,10}(the)/i
```

Answer (score 1):

Roger's answer will not work given your example since the letters in between the two words exceed 10 characters as well.  Changing Roger's example to:

`/\W*(the)\W*\s+([\w']+\s+){0,15}(account)|(account)\s+([\w']+\s+){0,15}(the)/i`

Will work.

A variation that would help control the return a bit, extract your example string and allow for more possibilities for the words in between.  I increased the letter count to 25 and changed it to allow for any character, and also added the quantifier `?` at the end to capture 0 or 1 of the occurrence which might help eliminate false positives having your regular expression find matches across other matches:

```
/(the.{0,25}?account)|(account.{0,25}?the)/gim
```

You currently have capture groups around `the` and `account` which I don't think is what you're wanting given the example you provided.  In my example above I have put the capture groups around the whole phrase since that's what you're intending on capturing.

Depending on how the string is in your spreadsheet a variation could be:

```
/(the.*?account)|(account.*?the)/gi
```

This would not limit the number of letters in your pattern and by adding the quantifier `?` to the end would not permit it to stretch across matching groups.

Lastly, the `\W*` at the beginning could cause some issues and in my simpler example I added the 'multiline' flag to allow for if there are line breaks in your string that you're using.